# How to prove Leray's theorem without using Sheaf cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a manifold. Leray's Theorem for Čech Cohomology states that if a covering $\mathfrak{U}$ is acyclic $(\check{H}^p(U_{i_0}\cap\ldots U_{i_k},F)=0$ for every finite intersections of elements in $\mathfrak{U}$ and every $p$) for a sheaf $F$, then
$$
\check{H}^q(\mathfrak{U},F)=\check{H}^q(X,F)
$$
where the first group is the Čech cohomology group depending of the covering and the second one is the Cech cohomology group independent of the covering (taking direct limits by refinements).
Every proof I have seen uses sheaf cohomology to compare $\check{H}^q(\mathfrak{U},F)$ with the sheaf cohomology group $H^q(X,F)$ and then conclude that it agrees with $\check{H}^q(X,F)$. Is there any way to prove it without using the strong machinery of sheaf cohomology? It is indeed a theorem in Čech Cohomology theory so my intuition is that we could avoid sheaf cohomology theory. Any references for (pure) Čech cohomology (proving theorems without using equivalences with other cohomology theories) are welcome.

Comment: I'm open to being corrected, but I don't see a good reason to expect that there is such a proof. The intuition for Čech cohomology should be that it is a right derived functor on the category of presheaves. The intuition for sheaf cohomology, on the other hand, is that it is a right derived functor on the category of sheaves. The theorem you want, however, is a statement about sheaves (I don't have a counter-example, but I believe it fails for presheaves), so it would seem only natural that the tools for sheaves rather than preshaves appear.

Comment: I finally proved it for paracompact Hausdorff spaces, because in those spaces we have the infinite long exact sequence for Čech cohomology. Using this it is not hard to prove the Leray's theorem. The reason behind is that in paracompact Hausdorff spaces, Čech cohomology agrees with sheaf cohomology, so the arguments used to prove the theorem using sheaf cohomology can be used here. But in the general case, where both cohomology theories are different, the acyclic covers compute the sheaf cohomology groups, not the Čech ones. So obviously it can't be done without sheaf cohomology.

Comment: @Thorgott what is Cech the derived functor of?

Comment: Globals is exact for presheaves

Comment: @FShrike The Čech cohomology is the derived functor of the $0$-th Čech cohomology, which is the group of compatible collections of local sections, i.e. of "gluing data", rather than presheaf global section. For separated presheaves, this is the same thing as global sections of the sheafification.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks, that’s a cool perspective. Do you know a reference that examines the Cech theory with this in mind? I don’t think it was mentioned in the algebraic geometry textbook I’ve got with me

Comment: @FShrike This perspective is very useful in relating Čech cohomology and sheaf cohomology (via a Grothendieck spectral sequence), yet I sadly lack a good reference for it. The results (as well as the argument Juan MF has found) are in Bredon's "Sheaf Theory", yet he doesn't really take this perspective and uses slightly more ad hoc arguments. The "canonical" reference ought to be Godement's "Topologie algébrique et théorie des faisceaux", but it is in French. If you find me in chat, I can forward you a short personal note I have on this stuff.